# JTree node referencing

Tags: string, jtree

I am trying to write a java version of a VBA treeview based application. The VBA application retrieves node information from a spreadsheet, retrieving the node keys as strings. Adding a child to the parent node would be as simple as:

```
Dim objNode as object

strParent="Parent"
strChild="Child1"
intIcon=1

set objNode=tvwMain.Nodes.Add(strParent,4,strChild,"New Child",intIcon)
```

In Java I could write this as:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode Parent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Parent Node");
root.add(Parent);

DefaultMutableTreeNode Child1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child Node");
Parent.add(Child1);
```

But what I want to do is effectively:

```
String strParent = "Parent";
DefaultMutableTreeNode Child1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child Node");

??strParent??.add(Child1);
```

where ??strParent?? is some code that points to a node call "Parent" via the String strParent. Is this possible?

Comment: It's a good start but unfortunately I didn't entirely understand what you want to do (getting a tree von an worksheet?) and especially where the problem is.

Comment: Maraca, thank you for your response. What I'm really looking for is a means of converting a string (i.e. the parent node's key) to a JTree node object so that I can add child nodes to it. Why? I have an Excel VBA application (that I want to convert to Java) that includes a worksheet containing an entire tree map. The worksheet has several columns including a parent key column, a child key column and a child text label column. I would like to cycle through, row by row, retrieving the various key values as strings, and creating JTree nodes accordingly.

Comment: So you need a way to get the values from the worksheet? Use Apache POI. Depending how it looks it might require some reading, for simple worksheets you can probably just copy one of the examples, but take care many of them are outdated, if you do it correctly you can support .xls and .xlsx (https://poi.apache.org/)

Comment: Maraca, thank you for you suggestion regarding Apache. Being a Java novice I'm still unclear how to covert strings to objects. In VBA if there was a tree node with a key of "K_1234" represented by strKey, I could copy its label value into a further string, strLabel, by strLabel=tvwMain.Nodes(strKey).Text. It's the ability to convert a string into an object (i.e. a JTree node) that I'm wondering about.

Comment: A String is already an (immutable) object ( = unchangeable, e.g. when you modify a String a new Object is created, unlike when you add a value to an array). To get a specific object you have to call the constructor or sometimes use a setter, using generics you can specify the type of object ... it really depends. Btw String comparison is done with equals or equalsIgnoreCase e.g. "hello".equals("world") would give false